# Django slug with id in url

Tags: django

How can made a url with `slug` and `id`, like:

`https://example.com/product/beauty-slug/1`

The `Product` model can accept repeated `title` product, and insted use `unique slug` i prefer use the `slug` with `id`

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='product_title')    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_change', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.product_title)
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And how use it in a `template`

product_list.html

```
<a href="{% url 'product_view' product.slug %}">see product</a>
```

urls.py

```
...
path('product/<slug:slug>', ProductView.as_view(), name='product_view'),
...
```

Thats works, but i know i gona have identical products title, so i think with `id` is better to my case, becouse if needed costumer can reference the order to seller with `id` number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As path you can use:

```
path('product/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>/', ProductView.as_view(), name='product_view'),
```

You thus can link to the URL with:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_view' product.slug product.pk %}">see product</a>
```

If you update the `product_change` URL pattern as well, the [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) of the model should be rewritten to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_change', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Every time I see the @willem-van-onsem name I know its going to be a good answer.   You sir, are a legend!  Thank you for all you do.